# word counter || python

Tags: python, counter

I want to print the number of words in a txt file having 1-20 letter. 
Tried this but it prints 20 zeroes instead. any idea?

edit - in the end the program should plot 20 numbers, each one is the number of words in the file containing 1-20 letters.

```
fin = open('words.txt')
for i in range(20):
    counter = 0
    for line in fin:
        word = line.strip()
        if len(word) == i:
            counter = counter + 1
    print counter,
```

Comment: The program logic is completely backward. Instead of iterating over the file and looking for words with 20 characters, you iterate over the file 20 times.

Comment: Are you looking for one number (count of words up to 20 chars) or 20 numbers (per potential length, how many words are there)?

Comment: looking for 20 numbers, meaning that the first number is the number of words in the file containing 1 letter, the 2nd number is the number of words conataining 2 letters etc...

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

To produce individual counts for each word length you can use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def word_lengths(f):
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():    # does not ignore punctuation
            yield len(word)

with open('words.txt') as fin:        
    counts = Counter(length for length in word_lengths(fin) if length <= 20)
```

This uses a generator to read the file and produce a sequence of word lengths. The filtered word lengths are fed into a `Counter`. You could perform the length filtering on the `Counter` instead.

If you want to ignore punctuation you could look at using [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.translate#str.translate) to remove unwanted characters, or possibly [`re.split(r'\W+', line)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) instead of `line.split()`.

---

Try it like this:

```
with open('words.txt') as fin:
    counter = 0
    for line in fin:
        for word in line.split():
            if len(word) <= 20:
                counter = counter + 1
    print counter,
```

This could be simplified to:

```
with open('words.txt') as fin:
    counter = sum([1 for line in fin
                      for word in line.split() if len(word) <= 20])
```

but that's playing code golf.

You can also use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) if it is practical to read the entire file into memory:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('words.txt') as fin:
    c = Counter(fin.read().split())
    counter = sum(c[k] for k in c if len(k) <= 20)
```

And no doubt there are many other ways to do it. None of the above expect or handle punctuation.

Comment: tried the first one u sent (haven't learned all the keywords in the second), gave me one number instead of 20. (i commented about it), have any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong, it's just that you clarified your requirement after asking the question. You should make the clarification in the question.

Comment: @Jonathan: answer updated to produce multiple counts.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this,`counter` shouldn't be in `for` loop,and you could use `len()` method to get the length of words:

```
with open("test") as f:
    counter = 0
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            if len(word)<=20:
                counter+=1
    print counter
```

Or my way:

```
import re

with open("file") as f:
    print len(filter(lambda x:len(x)<20,re.split('\n| ', f.read())))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

using regular expressions

```
import re

REGEX = r"(\b\S{1,20}\b)"
finder = re.compile(REGEX)

with open("words.txt") as out:
    data = out.read()

matches = re.findall(finder, data)

lst = [0 for _ in range(20)]

for m in matches:
    lst[len(m)] += 1

print(lst)
```

Comment: I edited my response based on clarified requirements provided by OP